# Avoid dragging switch on Switch.adaptive

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to avoid the dragging gesture to enable/disable the Switch.adaptive (flutter), this does not behave as Android switches behave.

The expected behavior would be to tap the switch.adaptive widget and get the value switched.

Now one has to drag the switch to a side to enable or disable it. It's quite inconvenient

Comment: I think it switches even if we just tap on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am warn you that i made this with custom

```
 AnimatedContainer(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    height: 40,
    width: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    color: togglevalue ?Colors.greenAccent[100] : Colors.redAccent[100].withOpacity(0.5),

  ),
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      AnimatedPositioned(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        top: 3.0,
        left: togglevalue?60.0 :0.0,
        right: togglevalue ? 0.0:60.0,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            toggleButton();
          },
          child: AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
            transitionBuilder: (Widget child,Animation<double> animation){
              return ScaleTransition(child: child ,scale: animation,);
            },
            child: togglevalue ?Icon(Icons.check_circle,color: Colors.green,size: 35,key: UniqueKey(),):Icon(Icons.remove_circle,color: Colors.red,size: 35,key: UniqueKey(),),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
  )
```